# Probability distribution on $X \in \{0, 1\}^N$ given that $\|X\|_1$ is distributed uniformly

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I've recently been diving into a bit of machine learning, and lots of probability theory has been coming up as a result. I took one course on probability and statistics in my first year of university and never touched it again, so, needless to say, I'm a bit rusty.

To train a certain neural network, I first need to generate training data. The inputs take the form of binary strings $x$ of length $N$, so that the sample space is just $\{0, 1\}^N$. I would like to take a random sample so that there is roughly an equal number of strings with the same taxicab norm:
$$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i, \qquad \text{ where } x = (x_1, \dots, x_N) \in \{0, 1\}^N.$$
It's not too hard to work out that the number of binary strings of length $N$ with $\|x\|_1 = k$ is just $N \choose k$, and that there are $2^N$ binary strings of length $N$ in total, so this could be rephrased as finding the distribution such that the probability of selecting some string $X \in \{0, 1\}^N$ given that $\|X\|_1 = k$ is
$$P(X \ \ \vert \ \ \|X\|_1 = k) = \frac{1}{N \choose k}.$$
From Bayes' Theorem,
$$P(X) = \frac{P(\|X\|_1 = k)}{{N \choose k} P(\|X\|_1 = k \ \ \vert \ \ X)}.$$
By design, $P(\|X\|_1 = k) = \frac1{N+1}$. Moreover, $P(\|X\|_1 = k \ \ \vert \ \ X) = 1$, so that
$$P(X) = \frac{1}{(N+1){N \choose k} }.$$
Is this argument correct? Does this distribution have some particular name?

---

**Edit:** By "binary string of length $N$," I really mean a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose components are all either $0$ or $1$.For $N=4$, there are $2^4 = 16$ possible binary strings of length $4$, some examples of which are:
$$x_1 = (0, 0, 1, 0), \ x_2 = (1, 1, 0, 0), \ x_3 = (0, 1, 1, 1).$$
The taxicab metric is introduced to count the numbers of $1$s that appear in the string. In the above examples, we see that
$$\|x_1\|_1 = 1, \ \|x_2\|_1 = 2, \ \| x_3\|_1 = 3.$$
An example of my goal in the case that $N=4$ would be to sample, say, $100$ points in such a way that there are $20$ strings containing no $1$s, $20$ strings containing one $1$, $20$ strings containing two $1$s, etc. (allowing for repetition).

Comment: Aren't there $N+1$ possible norms ($0$ through $N$), not just $N$ norms? Otherwise this looks correct.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah yes, you are absolutely right!

Comment: Would you mind to give an example, say, an example of strings consisting of $N=4$ binary digits to illustrate what probability you are looking for ?

Comment: @user295357 I've added an edit to my question to clarify the set-up for $N=4$

Comment: Considering your goal what role a probability should play? Obviously in your example the number of strings with a given norm does not depend on the norm.

Comment: @user It's true that the particular norm doesn't really matter here, the taxicab norm was just a convenient way to count the number of $1$s that appear in the string. Ultimately, I am looking for the probability of selecting a particular string, given that the norms of the strings are uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE.** This answer pertains to the original version and 1st revision of OP's question, in which OP required both $\|X\|_1$ and $(X \mid \|X\|_1 = k)$ are uniformly distributed on their respective range.

---

Your original argument is correct, modulo some rectification:

> **Result.** Let $X_N$ be a random binary string of length $N$ such that
>
> 1. $\|X_N\|_1$ is equally likely to be any of the values $0, 1, \ldots, N$, and
> 2. Given that $\{\|X_N\|_1 = k\}$, $X_N$ is equally likely to be any of the binary strings with taxicab norm $k$.
>
> Then the distribution of $X_N$ satisfies
> $$ \mathbf{P}(X_N = x) = \frac{1}{(N+1)\binom{N}{\|x\|_1}}. \tag{*} $$

This formula, although mathematically correct, does not directly tell us how to sample binary strings from the distribution of $X_N$ efficiently (without needing to tabulate the values of $\mathbf{P}(X_N = x)$ for all the $2^N$ possible values of $x$).

Thankfully, there is an efficient way of sampling from the distribution of $X_N$ via making a connection between the distribution of $X_N$ and a well-known stochastic process.

> **Pólya's Urn.** Suppose we have an urn containing $1$ black ball ● and $1$ white ball ○. We proceed to draw balls at random from the urn. On the $i$-th draw, we define
>
> $$ C_i = \begin{cases}
> 1, & \text{if a black ball ● has been drawn}, \\
> 0, & \text{if a white ball ○ has been drawn}.
> \end{cases} $$
> Also, after the color of the drawn ball has been observed, we return the ball to the urn, with an additional ball of the same color. Then:
>
> **Theorem.** $\tilde{X}_N = (C_1, \ldots, C_N)$ and $X_N$ have the same distribution.
>
> *Proof.* See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model#Exchangeability).

Below is a python code for simulating this process (assuming you have imported `numpy` library as `np`, as per the sacred tradition):

```
def polya_urn(n):
    b = 1
    w = 1
    res = [0] * n
    for i in range(n):
        res[i] = np.random.binomial(1, b / (b + w))
        if res[i] == 1:
            b += 1
        else:
            w += 1
    
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you, this was precisely the problem that I was trying to solve. My apologies for the edits, I momentarily got confused by the (now deleted) comments and hastily edited the original question. I've since put it back to how things were in the first edit. The code is also nice to see, it's more elegant than the way that I generated the samples of interest using nested for loops.

Comment: @infinitylord, No problem. It was quite an enjoyable question to me! :)

Comment: @user295357, I apologize for writing $X$ instead of $X_N$, which might be the source of confusion for you. After the correction, note that $X_N$ takes values in $\{0,1\}^N$. So, what is true is that $$\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^N} \mathbf{P}(X_N=x) = 1, $$ which is indeed true by grouping the summands according to the value of $\|x\|_1$.